# What programming languages always learned in computer science B.Sc.?

Tags: formal-languages, education

Even if programming by itself is not an [integral part of computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116666/is-coding-a-concept-in-this-theoretical-logical-field-of-study),
I would bet any B.Sc. student learns fundamentals of binary code, fundamentals of assembly code and at least one high programming language (above assembly).

What programming languages always learned in computer science B.Sc.?

<sub>I define programming as: *writing source code in one or more computer languages, of the programming language type*.</sub>

Comment: Might be more appropriate for [cseducators.se].

Comment: Anecdotally, here are some popular language: C/C++/Java, Scheme/relatives, python. In other disciplines, people might learn Fortran or matlab.

Comment: I don't understand what " learned in any B.A in computer science, in this planet" means.  Are you asking for a summary of all languages that have ever been taught in any B.A. program?  If so, this sounds too broad for this platform.  If not, can you [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Hello @D.W. I have tried to edit; at the moment, I can't see how to better phrase it. Thank you,

Comment: How many B.A. (as opposed to B.Sc.) CS programmes are there? This might be a question about one top English university.

Comment: I am sorry -  my mistake. I often use B.A as a general term for first academic degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no programming language that is taught in every computer science B.A. program. There is a lot of variation in what languages are used to teach material, in different programs.  For instance, when I took computer science classes, I learned only C and Standard ML.  There are other other programs where you might learn (for example) Python and Java.  If you choose any one programming language, I would imagine you can find some B.A. programs that teach that language and others that don't.

Learning a specific programming language is usually not the main point of a computer science education. The goal is to learn concepts and skills, and teaching any one programming language is just a way to support that goal.